# ibm watson text-to-speech word translation

Tags: speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I am currently using IBM Watson's text-to-speech API, and am working on some translation customization of some specific words. I was wondering what you guys think I should do. In the following text:

```
the company estimates revenues to be $194MM to 200MM
```

IBM Watson will pronouce the "MM" as "M M", instead it should say "millions". I don't think I want to translate "MM" to "millions". Is there a way to tell Watson that if "MM" occurs after some number, it's pronounced as "millions" instead of "M M"?

Also, does capitalization make any difference? Is "mm" the same as "MM"?

Comment: I think you'll have to replace all MM with "millions" in this case

Comment: Yeah, as you suggest Watson should handle this in a better way, for the moment you will need to the mapping yourself...

Answer (score 1):

If you want MM to be read as "millions", there must be a "$" preceding the number.  The text-to-speech engine can't blindly change MM to millions because it may inappropriate in some contexts.  For example, it could represent millimeters.

In your example, you should change 200MM to $200MM.